# Рендер изображения из SWF [SWF -> PNG]

Tags: php, actionscript, swf

Доброго времени суток.

Очень интересует решение следующей ситуации. Имеется SWF файл, который производит ренедр 3D модели. Имеется ExternalInterface, который покажет, когда завершился рендер.

**Задача:** вывести итоговое рендер-изображение в png формат средствами, желательно, PHP. Исходников SWF'ки нет. При декомпиляции обратная компиляция не проходит из-за ошибок декомпила. Тулзы типа wkhtmltopdf - не вариант.

Интересует либо какая-то **тактика извлечения финишного изjбражения**, либо **встраивание функции типа ExternalInterface** в уже скомпилированный SWF файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Поместить "подопытную" флешку, в другое флеш приложение, изображение снять оттуда.
- Попробовать декомпиляцию другими средствами, например - AS3 Sorcerer.
- Если флешка использует входные данные в формате известных 3д движков (alternativa, away, papervision), можно попытаться перехватывать и рендерить своей флешкой.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Подозреваю, что первый вариант будет наиболее оптимальным в моей ситуации.

Comment: Не за что, минус у варианта правда есть, это не PHP вариант, нужен человек знающий AS3.

Comment: Как я понимаю, надо вставить SWF в новый ролик, потрудиться с передачей переменных из родительского файла в дочерний, снять Loader.content (класс DisplayObject), конвертировать его в Bitmap, сделать, например, его Base64encode и через функцию в родительском файле передать результат в нужный .php файл.

Поправьте меня, если я не прав.

Comment: Почти правильно. 
Конвертируем примерно так 

    bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(height, width);
    bd.draw(Loader.content); // рисуем в битмап то что отрисовалось в 3д.